# Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am trying to build a tagging system using [taggingJS](https://github.com/sniperwolf/taggingJS) on the frontend and [laravel-tagging](https://github.com/rtconner/laravel-tagging) on the backend. I got them both working separately, but I cannot get the tags generated by taggingJS to enter the database.

My Laravel controller looks like this:

```
public function storeData(Request $request)
{
    $link = new Links;
    $link->tag_name = $request->taggone;
    $link->save();

    $link->tag(explode(',', $request->taggone));
    $link->save();

    return view('pages.postdata', compact('tags'));
}
```

The HTML code looks like this:

```
<div class="example-wrapper">
    <div class="tags well">
        <label for="tag" class="control-label">Tag</label>
        <div data-tags-input-name="taggone" id="tag"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I left taggingJS' Javascript unchanged like this (I am not sure if it is even relevant to this issue):

```
<script>
// jQuery on Ready example
(function( $, window, document, undefined ) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var t = $( "#tag" ).tagging();
        t[0].addClass( "form-control" );
        // console.log( t[0] );
    });
})( window.jQuery, window, document );
</script>
```

If I understand it correctly, the tags input into the field `taggone` are supposed to be requested by the controller and saved into the database. But when I submit the form I get the error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array,
>   string given, called in
>   /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php
>   on line 678

Can I have an advice on how to get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're passing a string (instead of an array) from your form. Try to adjust the `html` by adding **[]** to the **taggone** input like this:

```
<div data-tags-input-name="taggone[]" id="tag"></div>
```

If you're still receiving the same error, post the complete error message somewhere.

Comment: Yeah adding [] didn't help. I put the complete error message here: http://freetexthost.com/klzbomsrte

Comment: The error is on the date (created_at & updated_at) fields when saving tag_name, not the tags:

`Grammar->parameterize('2016-05-11 07:49:31')`. How is the Links model declared?

Comment: This is my links model:
`<?php

namespace App;

use Conner\Tagging\Taggable;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Links extends Model
{
    use Taggable;

    protected $table = 'tagging_tagged';
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way

```
public function storeData(Request $request)
{
    $link = new Links;
    $link->tag_name = $request->taggone;
    $link1 = $link->save();  //Store it to a variable

    //If your $request->taggone already an array you don't have to explode it, directly use $link1->tag($request->taggone);
    // Explode if it's a string and use $link1->tag(explode(',', $request->taggone));

    $link1->tag($request->taggone); //In case $request->taggone array

    //OR

    $link1->tag(explode(',', $request->taggone)); //In case $request->taggone string

    $link1->save();

   return view('pages.postdata', compact('tags'));
  }
```

Comment: I changed `tag` to `retag` and I get the same identical error. Perhaps it doesn't even get that far.

Comment: Do you have saparate table for tags?

Comment: There are two tables that came with the laravel-tagging package: `tagging_tagged` and `tagging_tags`